# Why in BCNS protocol both parties don't follow the exact same key extraction approach

Tags: key-exchange, lattice-crypto, lwe

Why in [BCNC key-exchange protocol](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/599.pdf#page=8) (page 8), *Bob* instead of:

$K_B \leftarrow \lfloor \bar v \rceil_{2q,2} \in \{ 0, 1\}^n$

do this instead:

$K_B \leftarrow rec(2bs', c) \in \{0, 1\}^n$.

or they are the same thing ... am I missing something? I don't understand the purpose of modular rounding function as defined [by Peikert in Lattice Cryptography for the Internet](https://web.eecs.umich.edu/~cpeikert/pubs/suite.pdf#page=9) (page 9) and [BCNS](http://eprint.iacr.org/2014/599.pdf#page=6) (page 6)

Because the idea is one party (i.e. Bob) sends a signal or reconciliation information (i.e. $c$) to other party (i.e. Alice) and then **both** should follow the exact same approach to get one bit from every coefficient.

Comment: This is Avery interesting question. But I need some ground work to answer

Comment: @Node.JS in Ring-LWE key-exchange the resulting polynomial of both parties are not exactly equal but the coefficients are very close. So the reconciliation method tries to extract a bit from every coefficient. What I don't understand is that both parties should follow the same reconciliation approach, maybe they are already doing the same thing approach but I did not understand. This is the wiki page for R-LWE key-exchange: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_learning_with_errors_key_exchange

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer of your question is in page $7$.

**Lemma2**:

For odd $q$, let $v=w+e\in Z_q$ for $w,e\in Z_q$ such that $2e\pm 1\in E \pmod q$. Let $\bar v=dbl(v)$ then $rec(2w,\langle \bar v\rangle _{2q,2})=\lfloor \bar v \rceil _{2q,2}$.